# updating composer / installing a new package conflicting packages

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I wanted to install a new package in a Laravel 7 application. I have tried direct composer require command and tried manually entering package name and updating composer command but both times it returns error as follows.
while using command  'composer require simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode'

```
 Problem 1
- chumper/zipper v1.0.0 requires illuminate/support 5.x -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- chumper/zipper[v1.0.1, ..., v1.0.3] require illuminate/support ^5.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- Root composer.json requires chumper/zipper ^1.0 -> satisfiable by chumper/zipper[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3].
```

while using command 'composer update'(with or without writing the new package details)

```
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires robincsamuel/laravel-msg91 dev-master -> satisfiable by robincsamuel/laravel-msg91[dev-master].
- robincsamuel/laravel-msg91 dev-master requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^7.0.1 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[dev-master, 7.0.1, ..., 7.2.0] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (~6.0)

  Problem 2
    - Conclusion: don't install chumper/zipper v1.0.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install chumper/zipper v1.0.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install chumper/zipper v1.0.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Root composer.json requires chumper/zipper ^1.0 -> satisfiable by chumper/zipper[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.2 (conflict analysis result)
     .........
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.30.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.30.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.30.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - chumper/zipper v1.0.0 requires illuminate/support 5.x -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev].
    - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[dev-master, v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev], laravel/framework[v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

my composer.json file is as followed:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.4.5",
    "africastalking/africastalking": "^2.3",
    "anhskohbo/no-captcha": "^3.2",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.6",
    "bigbharatjain/laravel-clickatell": "^1.0",
    "brian2694/laravel-toastr": "^5.53",
    "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "^4.1",
    "chumper/zipper": "^1.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "intervention/image": "^2.5",
    "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "laravel/passport": "^9.3.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.1",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
    "macsidigital/laravel-api-client": "^3.0",
    "macsidigital/laravel-zoom": "^4.0",
    "macsidigital/zoom": "^0.0.5",
    "nwidart/laravel-modules": "^7.1",
    "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "^1.14",
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0",
    "rahulreghunath/textlocal": "^1.0",
    "renatomarinho/laravel-page-speed": "^1.8",
    "robincsamuel/laravel-msg91": "dev-master",
    "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.37",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "^1.18.1",
    "twilio/sdk": "^5.31",
    "unicodeveloper/laravel-paystack": "^1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.3",
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
    "laravel/ui": "~2.0",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator": "^4.8",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
            "laravel/telescope"
        ]
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Modules\\": "Modules/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/Helper.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
```

}

Please help me resolve this problem I am hard stuck here for hours with no proper solution I could find on internet.

Comment: this package doesn't support your current version of Laravel  if you have recent Laravel downgrade it to version 7

Comment: https://github.com/Ne-Lexa/php-zip , you can use this php package on Laravel project normally or any other php package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chumper/zipper v1.0.0 requires illuminate/support 5.x` is the most important part of that output: the given package is only compatibel with Laravel v5, while your `composer.json` contains the requirement `"laravel/framework": "^7.0"`